# Freeze Image in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, images

I have a spreadsheet (see screenshot below). I want to freeze the image so when I scroll down, the image always stays visible while text rows are scrolled. How can I do this?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I told Emanuel the same thing. Excel is not designed for this. It's a spreadsheet. This was covered in another area before. The user wants an image to hover over the spreadsheet. It's not possible. I've stated, one would have to create an object in VB, create a routine for target object and move image. This is a VB-program script, not Excel functionality.

Comment: Adding to my comment above. Excel is easy to use, hence its popularity. If you want to create a Form in MS Access with an adjacent table, it would be more befitting your wishes. Otherwise if you want to keep using Excel what whatever your purposes are, you'd have to open in the image in image-viewing-software and resize the windows for viewing both Excel and the Image at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column or row that you want to freeze, go to the "View" tab on the toolbar up top, and hover over "Freeze".  This will present many options for you to choose from on how to freeze select portions of your screen.